# Merge element data in automatic

Tags: xml, notepad++

Goal:
Fullfill the requested result according to the picture without doing manual work.

Problem:
How should I enable to do it when you lots of xml code and data about 60 MB.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Notepad++ (I'm using the latest version 6.5.1) press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> (or go to menu `View` > `Collapse Level` > `2`) to collapse all `<user>` elements. This will produce the exact same result as in your right image.

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> to uncollapse them.